# Comparing values across matrices with a tolerance range

Tags: matlab, matrix, comparison

I have 4 matrices  having X,Y,Z co-ordinates of different points.say the matrices are:

A=[ 1 2 5 5; 2 3 4 4; 44 5 65 55]

B=[ 1 3 4 5; 2 3 14 146; 4 5 45 1]

C=[ 2 4 5 6 ; 4 5 6 8; 3 44 5 66]

D=[4 5 6 8; 1 3 4 5; 12 3 4 5]

I want to check whether there are any common point across the four matrices. I have a tolerance of +/- 1 for each of X,Y,Z.

I can run a loop for this but there is the problem of complexity coming up:
when the number of matrices increases the the complexity of the code increases hugely. Any way out regarding this?

Any better procedure regarding the problem?

Comment: you should share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I am assuming you are looking for indices i,j for which A(i,j)==B(i,j)==C(i,j)==D(i,j), within some tolerance? If so this code will work.

```
A=[ 1 2 5 5; 2 3 4 4; 44 5 65 55];
B=[ 1 3 4 5; 2 3 14 146; 4 5 45 1];
C=[ 2 4 5 6 ; 4 5 6 8; 3 44 5 66];
D=[4 5 6 8; 1 3 4 5; 12 3 4 5];

% concatenate A,B,C,D into a Nrow x Ncol x Nvars matrix
M = cat(3, A,B,C,D);

% find maximum and minimum along dimension 3
maxVal = max(M, [], 3);
minVal = min(M, [], 3);

% find which row,col indices have a range within 0.00001
valRange = maxVal - minVal;
matchPoints = (valRange <= 0.00001);

% boolean value representing if any match was found
matchFound = any(matchPoints(:));
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reply.I wrote this function to compare two matrices:

```
function [comp] = compare( A, B )

[m,n]= size(A);
[mm,nn]=size(B);
k=1;
comp=[];
for ii=1: m
for i=1:mm
    if A(ii,1) < (B(i,1)+2) & A(ii,1)> (B(i,1)-2)
        if A(ii,2) < (B(i,2)+2) & A(ii,2)> (B(i,2)-2)
            if A(ii,3) < (B(i,3)+2) & A(ii,3)> (B(i,3)-2) 
                comp(k,:)= [A(ii,:), B(i,:)];
                k=k+1;
            else continue
            end
        else continue
        end
    else continue
    end
end
end

end
```

My data is an output of activated co-ordinates of brain across several days. So I want to group regions ( across days) that are nearby each other in a cluster. I tried to attach a picture to explain what I want. But stack overflow is not allowing me.

I hope that this will clarify my post further.